# How to process .ts files used by flowplayer?

Tags: ffmpeg, flowplayer, mpeg2-ts

Flowplay seems to be used by jove.com

https://www.jove.com/video/59612/3d-kinematic-gait-analysis-for-preclinical-studies-in-rodents

Take the above URL as an example, it will use .ts files like this (via Google Chrome devtools)

https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_3.ts

But I am not sure how to make the .ts file viewable locally.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/3645/how-do-i-convert-ts-files-into-something-useful

I tried something like this. But I always get errors.

```
$ ffmpeg -i 50191_1.ts -c:v libx264 -crf 0 -c:a copy output.mp4
ffmpeg version 4.0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.0.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma
  libavutil      56. 14.100 / 56. 14.100
  libavcodec     58. 18.100 / 58. 18.100
  libavformat    58. 12.100 / 58. 12.100
  libavdevice    58.  3.100 / 58.  3.100
  libavfilter     7. 16.100 /  7. 16.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
  libswresample   3.  1.100 /  3.  1.100
  libpostproc    55.  1.100 / 55.  1.100
50191_1.ts: Invalid data found when processing input
```

Does anybody know how to convert the .ts files?

EDIT: I got something like this.

```
$ cat 59612_.m3u8
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:17
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612.key"
#EXTINF:16.683333,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_0.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_1.ts
#EXTINF:6.606600,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_2.ts
#EXTINF:16.683333,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_3.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_4.ts
#EXTINF:10.877533,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_5.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_6.ts
#EXTINF:7.907900,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_7.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_8.ts
#EXTINF:10.910900,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_9.ts
#EXTINF:9.676333,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_10.ts
#EXTINF:8.375033,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_11.ts
#EXTINF:12.645967,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_12.ts
#EXTINF:13.146467,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_13.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_14.ts
#EXTINF:6.840167,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_15.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_16.ts
#EXTINF:10.877533,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_17.ts
#EXTINF:16.683333,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_18.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_19.ts
#EXTINF:6.706700,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_20.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_21.ts
#EXTINF:16.683333,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_22.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_23.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_24.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_25.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_26.ts
#EXTINF:16.649967,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_27.ts
#EXTINF:8.308300,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_28.ts
#EXTINF:8.308300,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_29.ts
#EXTINF:5.672333,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_30.ts
#EXTINF:10.677333,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_31.ts
#EXTINF:16.683333,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_32.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_33.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_34.ts
#EXTINF:7.507500,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_35.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_36.ts
#EXTINF:16.683333,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_37.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_38.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_39.ts
#EXTINF:7.273933,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_40.ts
#EXTINF:16.683333,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_41.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_42.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_43.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_44.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_45.ts
#EXTINF:16.683333,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_46.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_47.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_48.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_49.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_50.ts
#EXTINF:16.683333,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_51.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_52.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_53.ts
#EXTINF:13.079733,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_54.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_55.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_56.ts
#EXTINF:13.113100,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_57.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_58.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_59.ts
#EXTINF:8.341667,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_60.ts
#EXTINF:6.573233,
https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_61.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Comment: That command should work. It’s likely the files has DRM.

Comment: How to decode it? Since the video can be seen in the browser, there must be a way to decode it?

Comment: First check if it’s DRMed. Then obtain the key. Then decrypt. Then decode.

Comment: Could you show the exact commands to use?

Comment: No. That not really possible because there is information missing. This sorta looks like a HLS fragment. Meaning there is a manifest. Can’t do anything more without the manifest.

Comment: But why the video can be seen in the browser without any problem?

Comment: How are you playing it in the browser? My bet is via a player that knows the location of the manifest file.

Comment: See the update. I think the commands can be derived from there?

Comment: You see the thing that says “key” that’s the decryption key. Download it, and decrypt. There are instructions on how to use OpenSSL to do that on stackoverdlow/google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612.key"`

This HLS videostream is encrypted. AES-128 is not DRM, so with the key present it can be decrypted.

### HLS videostream

The easy way is to just open the HLS videostream with FFmpeg (which it automatically decrypts) and cut the desired segment:

```
ffmpeg -ss 32 -i https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_.m3u8 -t 17 -c copy output.mp4
```

- `-ss 32`: skip to 32s.
- `-t 17`: set duration to 17s.
- `-c copy`: perform a stream-copy (no loss in quality).

### Individual segment

This requires you to decrypt the segment yourself.

When you download the decryption key `59612.key`, you'll see a lot of gibberish: `Aæª~ý÷øŽ©ýÛO®ø`.
You'll have to convert this to a hex binary representation. This can be done with `hexdump`...

```
curl -s https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612.key | hexdump -e '16/1 "%02x"
41e61c18aa7efdf7f88ea9fddb4faef8
```

...or with one of my favorite tools, [`xidel`](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html):

```
xidel -s https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612.key -e 'x:string-to-hexBinary($raw)'
41E61C18AA7EFDF7F88EA9FDDB4FAEF8
```

Next you can decrypt the 60th segment (for instance) with `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg \
-key 41E61C18AA7EFDF7F88EA9FDDB4FAEF8 \
-iv 0000000000000000000000000000003C \
-i crypto:https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_60.ts \
-c copy \
output.mp4
```

- `-iv 0000000000000000000000000000003C`: `60` (decimal) = `3C` (hexa-decimal).

...or with `openssl`:

```
openssl \
aes-128-cbc \
-in <(curl -s https://cloudflare2.jove.com/CDNSource/hls/59612/59612_60.ts) \
-out 59612_60-decrypted.ts \
-d -iv 60 -K 41E61C18AA7EFDF7F88EA9FDDB4FAEF8
```